# proving that if $z$ is a root of $A+B$, it is not a root of $B$ & finding common roots of $A$ and $B$

Tags: polynomials

for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $A$ and $B$ two polynomials as such:

$A\left(X\right)=nX^{n+1}-\left(n+1\right)X^n+1$

$B\left(X\right)=X^n-nX+\left(n-1\right)$

I'm struggling with the two following questions:

1. Show that if $z \in \mathbb{C}, z \not= 1$ and z is a root of $(A+B)(X)$, then $B(z) \not= 0$
2. Find the common roots of $A$ and $B$

Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For part 1, we know that $(A+B)(X) = n(X^{n+1}-X^n-X+1) = n(X-1)(X^n-1)$. So for any root of $A+B$ we have $X^n=1$.

For part 2, observe that if $X$ is a root of both $A$ and $B$, it is also a root of $A+B$.

Comment: so, for part 2, the only common root is $1$, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right